# R: error with ggplot2 in loading ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I'd like to use [`ggraph` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/index.html), but loading it, I got this error:

```
library(ggraph)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggraph’:
 object ‘scale_type’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it? I'm not finding any answer on the Internet. Thanks in advance.

I am running on Windows 10 this version of R:

```
    > shortRversion()
[1] "R-3.5.1_2018-07-02"
```

Comment: have you tried to unintall and then re-install `ggplot2` with `dependencies = TRUE`?

Comment: Nope, thanks for the helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this specific error by reinstalling the latest `ggplot2` version.

```
remove.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

It seems that `ggraph` depends on this current version of `ggplot2`.